# C# Entity Framework count all instances of an object

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to count all instances of `Movie_Instance` that contain a foreign key of a movie in the `Movie` table.

Here is my code:

```
var query = entities.Movie.Join(entities.Movie_Instance, 
                                movie2 => movie.ID_Movie,        
                                movie_instance => movie_instance.FK_ID_Movie,
                                (movie2, movie_instance) => new { Movi = movie, Movie_Instanc = movie_instance })
                    .Where(data => data.Movi.ID_Movie == data .Movie_Instanc.FK_ID_Movie 
                                   && data .Movi.ID_Movie == movie.ID_Movie)
                    .SelectMany(e => entities.Movie_Instance).Count();
```

What I get when I run this is an error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'DBFilmy.Movie'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

[EDIT]

[image: Movie and Movie_Instance]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJh2P.jpg)

`Movie_instance` contains instances of `Movie`. It's connected using foreign key (`FK_ID_Movie -> ID_Movie`) I have multiple instances of `Movie` and each of them is stored in `Movie_Instance`. I'd like to count how many instances of `movie` I have (`movie` is an object of `Movie` type)

Here is where I get movie:

```
var x = entities.Movie
                .Where(c => c.Title.Contains(_title)
                            && c.Director.Contains(_director)
                            && c.Category.Contains(_category));

foreach (var movie in x)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a working solution:

```
var query = entities.Movie.Join(entities.Movie_Instance,
                            s => s.ID_Movie,
                            c => c.FK_ID_Movie,
                            (s, c) => new {s, c}).Where(sc => sc.c.FK_ID_Movie == movie.ID_Movie).Select(sc => sc.s)
                        .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception typically occurs when you try to join a local (in-memory) list of objects with a `DbSet` in a context. It tells you (in rather cryptic language) that the local objects can't be translated to primitive values in a SQL statement.

But looking at your code I don't see any local list. Both `entities.Movie` and `entities.Movie_Instance` are `DbSet`s (unless you're doing something unexpected in your context) so I don't really understand the origin of the exception.

All that would only qualify as comment if it wasn't for a couple of concerns in your code.

- The first part of the `Where` clause is totally redundant. The join already matches `movie.ID_Movie` and `movie_instance.FK_ID_Movie`, so why do it again?
- The second part of the `Where` clause, `data.Movi.ID_Movie == movie.ID_Movie`, is also redundant: `data.Movi` and `movie` are the same entities.
- You don't need the join at all because you've already got a navigation property that contains the join: `movie.Movie_Instance`.

When you use the navigation property your code can be as simple as this:

```
var query = entities.Movie
    .SelectMany(e => entities.Movie_Instance).Count();
```

You'll see that the generated SQL contains a `JOIN`. EF does all the work for you.